# Improve ZeroMQ REQ/REP performance

Tags: zeromq

I'm using ZeroMQ 3.2.3 and CZmq 1.4.1. I gave the "Hello world" sample a try. That sample (https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/C), when using 10 concurrent clients, allows me to exchange at most 12500 messages per second on a Intel i7 (8 GB RAM, total 8 cores) on the localhost (Ubuntu 13.04).

I read ZeroMQ could handle much more. Am I doing something wrong, or missing something ?

Here is the sample code :

```
//  Hello World server

#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{
    //  Socket to talk to clients
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == 0);

    while (1) {
        char buffer [10];
        zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0);
        //printf ("Received Hello\n");
        zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0);
        //usleep (1);          //  Do some 'work'
    }
    return 0;
}



//  Hello World client
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf ("Connecting to hello world server...\n");
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");

    int request_nbr;
    for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 100000; request_nbr++) {
        char buffer [10];
//        printf ("Sending Hello %d...\n", request_nbr);
        zmq_send (requester, "Hello", 5, 0);
        zmq_recv (requester, buffer, 10, 0);
//        printf ("Received World %d\n", request_nbr);
    }
    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bottleneck you are hitting is because you aren't asynchronously streamlining your communication.

Try replacing your synchronous `REQ <-> REP` pattern with an asynchronous `ROUTER <-> DEALER` pattern.

The reason this can be much faster is that if the client can send consecutive requests without having to wait for each response in between. The cost of processing a single request/reply has two parts:

1. the cost of sending the messages "over the wire"
2. the cost of doing processing on request and/or reply on both client and server

An asynchronous pattern helps to greatly mitigate the cost of (2) when you are running a large number of consecutive requests.

Comment: I see. So now, let's assume I want the client to stop sending requests as soon as the server sends back "STOP" for example, wouldn't the ROUTER <-> DEALER pattern make it impossible since a few extra requests might already have been sent ?

Comment: @SCO No it's not impossible. Here's how you could do it: When the client receives "STOP," it simply stops sending requests from that point on. When the server sends "STOP," it simply ignores any requests it receives from that point on.

Comment: This looks good. Will have a look to ROUTER/DEALER examples then ! Thank you !

Comment: While this might be the correct answer I was genuinely hoping for an answer related to speeding up the REQ/REP pattern since I'm dealing with atomic operations. :(

Comment: @octanepenguin Who said asynchronous and atomic don't mix? ;) This won't stop you from formulating atomic requests. Formulate each request as describing a transaction.  "If the state is X, atomically change it to Y. Return whether the change was made or not." This is an atomic operation but can easily be sent as an asynchronous request.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in looking for nanoMsg style of REP-REQ, here is a nice snippet on how to combine zeroMQ ROUTER sockets and NanoMSG REP-REQ:

Combining ZeroMQ and NanoMsg for Serving Web-requests: http://my-classes.com/2014/04/26/combining-zeromq-and-nanomsg-for-serving-web-requests/